# How to send char to a serial port?

Tags: linux-kernel

I would like to send some char to a serial port in Linux (specifically to USB device registered as /dev/USB) by kernel module. I found a shell named tty line discipline but I'm beginner and I don't know how to make something like this. Could you tell me how can I do it or show me some example?

Comment: show your code or searching on google

Comment: *"specifically to USB device registered as /dev/USB"* -- That's not what a conventional USB device would do.  *"send some char to a serial port ... by kernel module"* -- Seems like a questionable plan.

Answer (score -1):

For basic testing purpose, you can send a char or characters by redirecting user buffer to your tty device.

### For instance :

root@vkalyanam:~# ls /dev/tty
Display all 102 possibilities? (y or n)
root@vkalyanam:~# ls /dev/ttyUSB
ttyUSB0  ttyUSB1
root@vkalyanam:~#

root@vkalyanam:~# 
root@vkalyanam:~# 
root@vkalyanam:~# echo data > /dev/ttyUSB0
root@vkalyanam:~#

This means, you have sent 'd', 'a', 't', a' characters to your serial (USB Gadget device).

Internally, kernel invoke ttyUSB device to transmit characters out.(to other end of your USB).

-Thanks